# How install platform application on server to avoid local installation for each user

Tags: java, netbeans, installation, platform

I have an application that I need to install to my users. The application is a Netbeans Platform and I install it using the installer .exe generated by Netbeans. Of course the installation is done locally for each user. The number of users has been increasing lately and sometimes I need install the application to 10 users in one day. So I installed the application in a Work Station with Windows 7 into a public folder and create a shortcut in a public k: drive. The user can run the application from this shortcut. This was OK but there is a limited access of 20 connections in Windows 7.

Now, I can make another installation in other Work Station to get 20 more connections but this is not a good solution.

My question is:

- There is a standard solution for this problem?
- There is a way to install the application in a server to give access to all my users and I do not need to install locally for each of them?
- I am doing something out of the standards for Netbeans Platform?
- What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need an application delivery solution. This can be done using one of a number of solutions including:
Microsoft Windows Server and RemoteApp 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755055(v=ws.11).aspx, 
Citrix XenApp https://www.citrix.com/products/xenapp-xendesktop/, 
Parallels Application Publishing https://www.parallels.com/products/ras/features/application-publishing/,
NoMachine and maybe others. It's not uncommon for companies to use centralized servers for application delivery (or even desktop delivery) to large number of clients. Since Netbeans runs on Linux you can even cook a free solution using FreeNX server.